# How can I use a regex to replace a character that is inside two other specific characters?

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on implementing a way to allow HTML in a field that I have with PHP. The characters are saved to the database as they are inputted, so when I print them to the screen later on, I want the HTML to be respected (security is not an issue here, so please don't make it one). What I need right now is a way to change any `&quot;` instances to the proper `"` character, but only when it falls inside an HTML declaration (i.e., `<` and `>` characters). When it's not inside these characters, it shouldn't be changed.

What is the proper way to do something like this with regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/&quot;(?=[^<>]*+>)/', '"', $str);
```

From your description I gather you mean "inside an HTML **tag**" (*declaration* doesn't really mean anything in this context).  I'm also assuming there can't be any `'<'` or `'>'` characters inside the tag (because they *are* legal in quoted attribute values).

The lookahead `(?=[^<>]*+>)` asserts that there is a right angle bracket up ahead, and no other angle brackets between here and there.  Assuming every angle bracket is part of a balanced pair, that should mean the current position is inside an HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to find tags? `X` is the character, but may be replaced by a string.

```
<[^>]*X[^>]*>
```

A practical example, which finds links that start with `<a href`:

```
<a href="([^"]*)"[^>]*>.
```